# When should glInvalidateBufferData be used?

Tags: opengl, asynchronous, optimization, invalidation

OpenGL provides the functions `glInvalidateBufferData` and `glInvalidateBufferSubData` for invalidating buffers.

What these functions do according to the OpenGL wiki:

> When a buffer or region thereof is invalidated, it means that the contents of that buffer are now undefined.

and

> The idea is that, by invalidating a buffer or range thereof, the implementation will simply grab a new piece of memory to use for any later operations. Thus, while previously issued GL commands can still read the buffer's original data, you can fill the invalidated buffer with new values (via mapping or glBufferSubData) without causing implicit synchronization.

I'm having a hard time understanding when this function should be called and when it shouldn't. In theory, if the contents of the buffer are going to be overwritten it makes absolutely no difference if the previous contents were trashed or not. Does this mean that a buffer should be called before every write? Or only in certain situations?

Answer (score 2):

> In theory, if the contents of the buffer are going to be overwritten it makes absolutely no difference if the previous contents were trashed or not.

You're absolutely right.

In essence whether you call [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) or [`glInvalidateBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glInvalidateBufferData.xhtml) you're achieving the same end goal. The difference is that with [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) you're more saying "*I need this much memory now*", which in turn means that the old memory is discarded. However with [`glInvalidateBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glInvalidateBufferData.xhtml) you're saying "*I don't need this memory anymore*". The same goes for [`glInvalidateBufferSubData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glInvalidateBufferSubData.xhtml) vs [`glBufferSubData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) as well as all the other `glInvalidate*()` functions.

The key here is that if you have a buffer, and you currently aren't needing it anymore however you're keeping the handle for later use. Then you can call [`glInvalidateBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glInvalidateBufferData.xhtml) to tell that the memory can be released.

The same goes for [`glInvalidateBufferSubData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glInvalidateBufferSubData.xhtml). If you suddenly don't need the last half chunk of the memory assigned to the buffer, then now your driver knows that this chunk of memory can be reassigned.

> When should glInvalidateBufferData be used?

So to answer your question. When you have a buffer laying around and you don't need the memory anymore.